# How to avoid formatting all text when execcommand in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, execcommand

I have a project I am working on where autoformatting of text needs to occur as a user types inside of some form of HTML/javascript input. Right now the input is being implemented as a contenteditable HTML element. The way I was handling this was to use keyDown to determine what will be added and using execcommand to set the proper formatting before the text is added for the key event. This works perfectly for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. But I am running into a rather odd issue in IE. Using execcommand on a selection or toggling its values when the cursor is at the end or beginning of the editable content works perfectly. The problem is that when nothing is selected and the cursor is not at the end or beginning of the text then execcommand affects all of the contenteditable content, not just the text added by the current event.

Here is a quick coded example that shows the issue fairly clearly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function styleActive(style) {
        var isActive = false;
        if(style) {
          isActive = document.queryCommandState(style);
    }
        return isActive;
      }
      function setStyle(style, desiredState) {
        if(style) {
          if(styleActive(style) != desiredState) {
            document.execCommand(style, false, null);
          }
        }
      }
      function autoFormat(e) {
        var keynum;
        var keychar;
        var numcheck;
        if(e.which) {
          keynum = e.which;
        }
        keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
        numcheck = /\d/;
        if(numcheck.test(keychar)) {
          setStyle("subscript", true);
        } else {
          setStyle("subscript", false);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      p._editable, p._editable p {margin:0px;}
      p._editable {margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px; margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("editable").focus(); document.execCommand("subscript", false, null);'>Sub</button>

    <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("editable").focus(); document.execCommand("superscript", false, null);'>Sup</button>
    <div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;min-width:30px;border-style:solid; border-width:5px;">
        <p id="editable" class="_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeydown="autoFormat(event);"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>document.getElementById("editable").focus();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically it is just a p element inside of two divs that expand with it as it expands and the format state is altered based upon keyDown events from the p element. All it is doing is making sure subscript is active if the key is a digit, otherwise it makes sure it is not active. The easiest way to reproduce the issue is to type some numbers and then use the arrow key to move cursor back through them. What I am seeing is that after the initial move all the subscripted numbers now become normal because execcommand for subscript is being called since the arrow key is not a digit key. Another way to cause it to happen is to click on the sub or sup button when in the middle of text with nothing selected.

Ideally what would be nice is to understand if possible what is happening and a way to make toggling the formatting with nothing selected not affect everything so that I can continue to use this way of handling things. If that is not possible any suggestions of ways to handle this would be greatly appreciated. The desired end result is a text input in javascript/HTML that I will popup when someone clicks, then as they type I can determine the contents of the text and what is about to be added and format the output accordingly, maintaining the cursor position as a text input normally would. I am only worried about newer browsers so IE9 and newer versions of the major browsers that support HTML5.

Currently the best idea I can come up with is to swallow the key input at keyDown for cases where I am seeing the issue and attempt to insert the character via DOM manipulation.

Comment: So the only real solution that I came up with that worked well was by using the [Rangy library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) and on keydown when I wanted to change the styling I would check the state of where I was in the text nodes and DOM. Then if it was a case where I was going to be changing the style in the middle of an item that wasn't that style I had to programmatically split the node/DOM element and insert a space character in there that I would programmatically select, since is a case where the browser was working it would work correctly.